# What modifications can I make in svmtrain of LIBSVM to improve the accuracy of my spam classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, octave, libsvm

I am using Octave version 5.2.0 and LIBSVM 3.24 to build a spam classifier.
Without using LIBSVM I got an accuracy of >99% on both test and train data.
But while using LIBSVM, I only get an accuracy of 68-69% .What modifications should I do on my LIBSVM options?
This is the code I used

```
model = svmtrain(X, y,'-c 0.1 -t 2 -s 0 -g 1000');
p = svmpredict(y,X,model);
```

Comment: What is the "without LibSVM" version?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the settings of LibSVM?

```
% libSVM options:
% -s svm_type: set type of SVM (default 0)
%   0 -- C-SVC
%   1 -- nu-SVC
%   2 -- one-class SVM
%   3 -- epsilon-SVR
%   4 -- nu-SVR
% -t kernel_type: set type of kernel function (default 2)
%   0 -- linear: u'*v
%   1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
%   2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
%   3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
% -d degree: set degree in kernel function (default 3)
% -g gamma: set gamma in kernel function (default 1/num_features)
% -r coef0: set coef0 in kernel function (default 0)
% -c cost: set the parameter C of C-SVC, epsilon-SVR, and nu-SVR (default 1)
% -n nu: set the parameter nu of nu-SVC, one-class SVM, and nu-SVR (default 0.5)
% -p epsilon: set the epsilon in loss function of epsilon-SVR (default 0.1)
% -m cachesize: set cache memory size in MB (default 100)
% -e epsilon: set tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001)
% -h shrinking: whether to use the shrinking heuristics, 0 or 1 (default 1)
% -b probability_estimates: whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)
% -wi weight: set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)
```

So your `-s 0 -t 2 -g 1000 -c 0.1` settings translate to a C-SVM (`-s 0`) with a Gaussian kernel (`-t 2`) with a large scaling (`-g 1000`) and a smaller than default cost for violations (`-c 0.1`).

I suggest to try it first with the default values (`-s 0 -t 2`), and than increase the cost `-c`. Your gamma looks ridiculously large but without knowing your data, none can judge this. Have a look on *hyperparameter optimization*, which exactly sets those values. There exists plenty of work on this but I am only familiar with regression analysis. If in doubt, do a global optimization on those parameters through `gridsearch` or `ga`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I was finally able to successfully use LIBSVM  to train my spam classifier.I just recently came to know that gamma was related to 1/sigma(and not sigma).Also I was able to choose apt parameters using gridsearch. But however I was able to get a better accuracy with Linear SVM. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: great! remember to up/downvote or accept the answer if you like ;)